# Spring security with AD Authentication and Database Authorization

Tags: spring, authentication, active-directory, spring-security

I'm trying to implement the solution of this question

> [Spring Security 3 Active Directory Authentication, Database Authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228932/spring-security-3-active-directory-authentication-database-authorization?answertab=active)

but i don't understand how to use the MyAuthoritySupplementingProvider .

Is there someone that can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think MyAuthoritySupplementingProvider should be specified in

```
<beans:bean id="activeDirectoryAuthenticationProvider"
        class="xxx.package.MyAuthoritySupplementingProvider">
    <beans:constructor-arg value="mydomain" />
    <beans:constructor-arg value="ldap://my URL :389" />
    <beans:property name="convertSubErrorCodesToExceptions" value="true"/>
</beans:bean>
```

i am not sure weather this will work or not but to get more detail you should refer to book "Spring Security 3" Chapter 9 for ldap and active directory configuration and options, this will help you understand this in better way instead of just going through SO post.