# How to configure AD authentication and DB authurization in spring security 3.1

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-ldap

I have gone through below question

[Spring Security 3 Active Directory Authentication, Database Authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228932/spring-security-3-active-directory-authentication-database-authorization)

Instead of delegate method we can configure in only spring security xml file.

Can you please guide me How we can do that.

This is working configuration for Spring security 2.5 But I don't know how to use in 3 or 3.1

```
<bean id="ldapAuthProvider" class="org.cmfrwk.security.spring.providers.ldap.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
        <security:custom-authentication-provider />
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.spring.security.spring.providers.ldap.BindAuthenticator">
                <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
                <property name="userSearch" ref="userSearch" />
                <property name="userDnPatterns">
                    <list>
                        <value>CN={0},OU=Users,OU=Laptop-Users,OU=Users,OU=XXX-EMPLOYEE,OU=XXX-XX-ADH,OU=XXX,DC=in,DC=XXXXX,DC=net</value>              
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.populator.UserDetailsServiceLdapAuthoritiesPopulator">
                <constructor-arg  ref="customUserDetailsService" />
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>

    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the documentation: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ldap.html

Comment: I have gone through the details but they added new classes for Active Directory. Can you give me idea how can implement

Comment: Corrected the link above to point to Spring security 3.1.x documentation (rather than 3.0.x) which includes the section on AD.