# Spring Security 3.1: Active Directory Authentication and local DB Authorization

Tags: authentication, spring-security, active-directory, spring-security-ldap

I am using Spring Security 3.1 for Active Directory authentication and a local db for loading the authorities. I have seen similar examples but it is still not clear for me what exactly I should use. My current settings in spring-security.xml is:

```
  <!-- LDAP server details -->
  <security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider ref="ldapActiveDirectoryAuthProvider" />
  </security:authentication-manager>


  <beans:bean id="ldapActiveDirectoryAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:constructor-arg value="${ldap.domain}" />
    <beans:constructor-arg value="${ldap.url}" />
    <beans:property name="useAuthenticationRequestCredentials" value="true" />
    <beans:property name="convertSubErrorCodesToExceptions" value="true" />
  </beans:bean>
```

I have a class let's call it: "BookStoreDbAuthPopulator.java". Inside this class, I am calling this method:

```
    // Load additional authorities and create an Authentication object
    final List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = loadRolesFromDatabaseHere();
```

What is not still clear for me: Which interface should "BookStoreDbAuthPopulator.java" implements in order to add the loaded authorities from db to the UserDetails? "UserDetailsContextMapper" or "GrantedAuthoritiesMapper" or "AuthenticationProvider"?

Based on this solution: [Spring Security 3 Active Directory Authentication, Database Authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228932/spring-security-3-active-directory-authentication-database-authorization?rq=1)
"BookStoreDbAuthPopulator.java" should implement "AuthenticationProvider". My doubt is if I should use "BookStoreDbAuthPopulator.java" as a property for "ldapActiveDirectoryAuthProvider" bean?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My final solution is "BookStoreDbAuthPopulator.java" implements "UserDetailsContextMapper".

```
public class BookStoreDbAuthPopulator implements UserDetailsContextMapper {

   // populating roles assigned to the user from AUTHORITIES table in DB
   private List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> loadRolesFromDatabase(String username) {

      //"SELECT ROLE FROM AUTHORITIES WHERE LCASE(USERNAME) LIKE ?"
      ...
   }

   @Override
   public UserDetails mapUserFromContext(DirContextOperations ctx, String username, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
      List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> allAuthorities = new ArrayList<SimpleGrantedAuthority>();
      for (GrantedAuthority auth : authorities) {
        if (auth != null && !auth.getAuthority().isEmpty()) {
           allAuthorities.add((SimpleGrantedAuthority) auth);
        }
      }
      // add additional roles from the database table
      allAuthorities.addAll(loadRolesFromDatabase(username));
      return new User(username, "", true, true, true, true, allAuthorities);
   }

   @Override
   public void mapUserToContext(UserDetails user, DirContextAdapter ctx) {
   }

}
```

Then in spring-security.xml

```
  <!-- AuthenticationManager: AuthenticationProvider, LDAP server details -->
     <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider ref="ldapActiveDirectoryAuthProvider" />
     </security:authentication-manager>

  <beans:bean id="ldapActiveDirectoryAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider">
     <!-- the domain name (may be null or empty). If no domain name is configured, it is assumed that the username will always contain the domain name. -->
     <beans:constructor-arg value="${ldap.domain}" />
     <!-- an LDAP url (or multiple URLs) -->
     <beans:constructor-arg value="${ldap.url}" />
     <!-- Determines whether the supplied password will be used as the credentials in the successful authentication token. -->
     <beans:property name="useAuthenticationRequestCredentials" value="true" />
     <!-- by setting this property to true, when the authentication fails the error codes will also be used to control the exception raised. -->
     <beans:property name="convertSubErrorCodesToExceptions" value="true" />
     <!-- for customizing user authorities -->
     <beans:property name="userDetailsContextMapper" ref="myUserDetailsContextMapper" />
  </beans:bean>
     <!-- Customizing UserDetail -->
  <beans:bean id="myUserDetailsContextMapper" class="com.mybookstore.mywebcomp.w.BookStoreDbAuthPopulator">
  </beans:bean>
```